# Is it possible to use Square's point of sale app without login?

Tags: square-connect

I'm developing an app that uses Square's point of sale app to make payment. However, as far as I know, our merchants need to login to the point of sale app before the payment can be made. My question is since we have the access token for Square-connect APIs, is it possible to use this token and other information such as `locationId`, `merchantId` etc. to make payments without logging into the point of sale app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for in-person payments, but you could use e-commerce anonymously.